# How can I show an overlay/popover on a Mac app that covers the entire window (including the navigation bar) with SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui, navigationsplitview

I am using SwiftUI to build a native macOS app and when using NavigationSplitView or NavigationStack the navigation/toolbar is always forced to the top. I've tried ZStack, .overlay and even manipulating the NSWindow but it is always still forced to the top.

Basic Example:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PopOverApp: App {
    @State private var isTopSnackbarPresented = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .background(.blue)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            Text("Detail")
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what method I've tried I still end up with the navigation toolbar on top like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a very hacky solution:

```
@main
struct StackOverflowTestApp: App {
    
    @State var overlay = false
    @State var window: NSWindow?
        
    var body: some Scene {

        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(overlay: self.$overlay)
                .if(self.overlay, transform: { view in
                    view.overlay(OverlayView(presented: self.$overlay))
                })
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.didBecomeKeyNotification)) { notification in
                    if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow {
                        self.window = window
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: self.overlay) { oldValue, newValue in
                    self.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = newValue == true ? true : false
                    self.window?.toolbar?.isVisible = newValue == true ? false : true

                    if let index = self.window?.toolbar?.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.itemIdentifier == .init("com.apple.SwiftUI.navigationSplitView.toggleSidebar") }) {
                        self.window?.toolbar?.removeItem(at: index)
                        if let index2 = self.window?.toolbar?.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.itemIdentifier == .init("com.apple.SwiftUI.splitViewSeparator-0") }) {
                            // this was trial and error, I don't know, why this is necessary
                            self.window?.toolbar?.removeItem(at: index2)
                        }
                        self.window?.toolbar?.insertItem(withItemIdentifier: .toggleSidebar, at: 0)
                    }
                }
        }
            
    }
}

struct OverlayView: View {
    
    @Binding var presented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .background(.blue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Button("Close") {
                self.presented = false
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Binding var overlay: Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Text("Sidebar")
        } detail: {
            Button("overlay") {
                self.overlay = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

extension View {
    /// Applies the given transform if the given condition evaluates to `true`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - condition: The condition to evaluate.
    ///   - transform: The transform to apply to the source `View`.
    /// - Returns: Either the original `View` or the modified `View` if the condition is `true`.
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

After hiding the toolbar, the `.toggleSidebar` button in the toolbar will be gone and I didn't find another solution as showed in the example. Maybe you will find a better one.